# How to iterate Node.js database query results in Java/ Android

Tags: java, android, json, node.js, iteration

I query a table in a database and got the following results :

> {"command":"SELECT","rowCount":4,"oid":null,"rows":[{"id":1,"title":"Cheese","primary_author":"9.99"},{"id":2,"title":"Cheese","primary_author":"9.99"},{"id":3,"title":"Cheese","primary_author":"9.99"},{"id":4,"title":"Cheese","primary_author":"9.99"}],"fields":[{"name":"id","tableID":9408343,"columnID":1,"dataTypeID":23,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"},{"name":"title","tableID":9408343,"columnID":2,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"primary_author","tableID":9408343,"columnID":3,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null,null,null],"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":false}

All this is in Json from a Node.js server.

How can I go about iterating the **rows**?

Thank you all in advance.

The following attempt breaks:

```
 // response
Log.v("MyApp", response);

JSONArray json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONArray(response);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject e;
    try {
        e = json.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.v("MyApp", "ID  : " + e.getString("id"));

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
```

at

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Log.v("MyApp", response);

JSONObject json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(response);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONArray jArr = json.getJSONArray("rows");

for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject e;
    try {
        e = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.v("MyApp", "ID  : " + e.getString("id"));

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @morteza-jalambadani. I used your answer and it works very well. Sorry for the late reply, and for accepting your answer late. I am grateful.